# Pandas: type error when creating a Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a minimally reproducible dataset (which is retrieved from an internal database) that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'manufacturer':['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Audi'],
                  'created_time':['2021-03-05T07:18:12.281-0600', '2021-03-04T15:34:23.373-0600', '2021-03-01T04:57:47.848-0600', '2021-02-25T09:31:37.341-0600'],
                  'action_time':['2021-03-05T08:32:19.153-0600', '2021-03-04T15:37:32.360-0600', '2021-03-01T08:37:39.083-0600', '2021-02-25T09:58:12.425-0600']})

df
    manufacturer    created_time                    action_time
0   BMW             2021-03-05T07:18:12.281-0600    2021-03-05T08:32:19.153-0600
1   Mercedes        2021-03-04T15:34:23.373-0600    2021-03-04T15:37:32.360-0600
2   Mercedes        2021-03-01T04:57:47.848-0600    2021-03-01T08:37:39.083-0600
3   Audi            2021-02-25T09:31:37.341-0600    2021-02-25T09:58:12.425-0600
```

I then create a custom column named `elapsed_time`:

```
df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])
df['action_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['action_time'])
time_threshold = pd.to_datetime('08:30').time()

df['created_time_adjusted']=df['created_time'].apply(lambda x:
                                                  x.replace(hour=8,minute=30,second=0)
                                                  if x.time()<time_threshold else x)

df['elapsed_time'] = (df['action_time'] - df['created_time_adjusted']).dt.total_seconds() /60
```

The updated dataframe looks as follows:

```
column_headers = ['manufacturer', 'created_time', 'action_time', 'created_time_adjusted', 'elapsed_time']
df = df.reindex(columns=column_headers)
df

    manufacturer   created_time                        action_time                        created_time_adjusted             elapsed_time
0   BMW            2021-03-05 07:18:12.281000-06:00    2021-03-05 08:32:19.153000-06:00   2021-03-05 08:30:00.281000-06:00  2.314533
1   Mercedes       2021-03-04 15:34:23.373000-06:00    2021-03-04 15:37:32.360000-06:00   2021-03-04 15:34:23.373000-06:00  3.149783
2   Mercedes       2021-03-01 04:57:47.848000-06:00    2021-03-01 08:37:39.083000-06:00   2021-03-01 08:30:00.848000-06:00  7.637250
3   Audi           2021-02-25 09:31:37.341000-06:00    2021-02-25 09:58:12.425000-06:00   2021-02-25 09:31:37.341000-06:00  26.584733
```

So far, so good.

The types look as follows:

```
df.dtypes
manufacturer                                             object
created_time             datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)]
action_time              datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)]
created_time_adjusted    datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-360)]
elapsed_time                                            float64
dtype: object
```

Finally, I try to pivot the data to see the mean `elapsed_time` by `manufacturer`.  I do so as follows:

```
pivoted_data = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index='manufacturer', values='elapsed_time', aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Which, ***on this toy data set***, gives:

```
pivoted_data

    elapsed_time
manufacturer    
Audi        26.584733
BMW         2.314533
Mercedes    5.393517
```

However, when I run this on the production dataset (which, to reiterate, **has the same datatypes**), I see the following error:

```
TypeError:  '<' not supported between instances of 'CustomFieldOption' and 'CustomFieldOption'
```

The error indicates that it's a problem with types.  But, I don't see how that can be when the types match between the toy dataset and the production dataset.

Does anyone know what's wrong here or how I can debug this further?

Thanks!

####################################################################

**UPDATE:**

After following the suggestion of @Icarwiz, I dug a little deeper and called the following on `manufacturer`:

```
df['manufacturer].unique()
```

This resulted in:

```
array([<DB CustomFieldOption:  value='BMW', id='32563'>,
       <DB CustomFieldOption:  value='Mercedes', id='32431'>,
       <DB CustomFieldOption:  value='Mercedes', id='32431'>,
       <DB CustomFieldOption:  value='Audi', id='28371'>],
      dtype=object)
```

So, this is a complex data type.  Any idea where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

You say "the same datatype", but considering that for manufacturer it is **object**, it doesn't prove anything, as it can be anything from simple **str** to very complex objects.

And here it seems you have things in your columns manufacturer that are not strings...

Try this to find them :

```py
df[df['manufacturer'].map(lambda x: type(x) is not str)]
```

EDIT :

Ok, so that's an answer... :)

Now you just have to manage with this kind of object that I don't know...
Educated guess, try converting your column to str with something like this :

```py
df['manufacturer'] = df['manufacturer'].map(lambda x: x.value)
```

But if it doesn't work you'll have to learn how this kind of object works...

```py
test_obj = df['manufacturer'].iloc[0]
print(dir(test_obj))
```

Comment: Running `df[df['manufacturer'].map(lambda x: type(x) is not str)]` results in the ENTIRE data frame.  Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: I updated the original post based on some further digging.  Not sure where to go from here.